# Visualizing Curve in Projective Space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand/visualize what the curves xy=1 and $y=x^3$ look like in projective space.

I'm familiar with the construction of the space, and how to homogenize the two curves as $xy=z^2$ and $yz^2=x^3$, respectively, but am having trouble understanding how to grasp what this "projection" actually looks like.

Comment: I'm sure you have seen the affine parts (over reals) of these two curves in school already. To get an idea of what happens near the line at infinity you should look at the other affine charts. You get those by letting $Z$ stay, and then set $Y=1$ or $X=1$ (i.e. dehomogenize a coordinate other than the "originally" dehomogenized $z$). You will see that the projective closure of $xy=1$ is nice and smooth everywhere (the other two affine parts look like parabolas), but $y=x^3$ has a cusp at the point with homogeneous coordinates $(X:Y:Z)=(0:1:0)$.

Comment: I'm not experienced in AG so I won't pontificate, but I find it easier to use different symbols for the homogeneous coordinates. Upper case coming handy there. So with your latter curve I would rather write the homogenized equation in the form $$YZ^2=X^3.\qquad(*)$$ The cusp becomes visible using the dehomogenized coordinates $u=X/Y$, $v=Z/Y$ as $(*)$ becomes (divide it by $Y^3$)
$$v^2=u^3.$$ This process makes it easier for me to figure out which points correspond to each other in various affine charts. Here $v=1/y$ and $u=x/y$ in the original $xy$-coordinates.